# how to use wget to download shared zip file from google drive?

Tags: wget

How do I download the zip files here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PYSJLae6m9Bb55NADlFUdtEKH9UHML-l using wget?

Answer (score 0):

The files you see in that link are a part of a script your browser executes when browsing to that URL, while `wget` is incapable of doing such things.
If you insist on using `wget` follow my answer, yet I encourage you to use any other available [cli utils](https://linuxhint.com/best_google_drive_clients_linux/) developed for google drive interaction using the terminal.

#### Using wget as a non dedicated google drive util:

What you need is the full URI of each of those files, and use it with `wget`.

You could get the direct URI by clicking with your right mouse button and choosing the "Get link option":

[image]

[image]

**Note:** make sure file sharing permissions are set to "**Anyone with link**", or else a direct `wget` download won't work (same goes for web browsers without a user logged in their google account).

Copy the link provided and replace the `file/d/` with `uc?id=` and replace at the end of the link the `/view?usp=sharing` with `&export=download`.

With the new link created use `wget` to download the file: `wget your_edited_link_here`

For example: `wget https://drive.google.com/uc?id=11xLT-f2SMYKZiJXrRU3zngqW&export=download`

**Note:** the link in the example won't work as I broke my file id intentionally so it won't share a real file from my drive.

Again, even if this method works it is really suggested to use standard utils such as [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive), [gdown](https://pypi.org/project/gdown/), [gshell](https://github.com/wkentaro/gshell) or any [other util](https://linuxhint.com/best_google_drive_clients_linux/) demonstrated at the link I pasted at the beginning.